# CSS Animations - Animation bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I'm trying to use `CSS` animations to animate a cube rotating, and pausing on each face for a set amount of time.

[Pen here](https://codepen.io/wearehuddle/pen/KXLjdv)

```css
@keyframes frontToLeft {
    75% { transform: rotateY(0); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(90deg); }
  }

  @keyframes leftToBack {
    75% { transform: rotateY(90deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
  }

  @keyframes backToRight {
    75% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(270deg); }
  }

  @keyframes rightToFront {
    75% { transform: rotateY(270deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
  }

  .cube-container {
    padding-top: 200px;
    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
  }

  .qube {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    animation-name: frontToLeft, leftToBack, backToRight, rightToFront;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 2s, 2s, 2s, 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s, 4s, 6s, 8s;

   * {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(125,125,125,0.8);
    }

    .front {
      transform: translateZ(100px);
    }

    .back {
      transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .top {
      transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
      transform-origin: top center;
    }

    .bottom {
      transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
      transform-origin: bottom center;
    }

    .left {
      transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
      transform-origin: center left;
    }

    .right {
      transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
      transform-origin: top right;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="cube-container">
  <div class="qube">
    <div class="front">front</div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="back">back</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Google Chrome and Edge, the animation seems to glitch, but in Firefox it works as intended.

I'd like the outcome to be:

- Front Face - Pause 2 seconds, rotate 2 seconds
- Left Face - Pause 2 seconds, rotate 2 seconds
- Back Face - Pause 2 seconds, rotate 2 seconds
- Right Face - Pause 2 seconds, rotate 2 seconds

Can anyone see where this would be going wrong? I have the Codepen preprocessing SCSS with prefixes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell testing this it looks like a bug. Nothing I've tried seems to work to correct the animation. Like you say, Firefox works as expected.

All I can think of as a potential fix is to combine it into one animation something like this:

```
@keyframes spinCube {
    20% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    25% { transform: rotateY(90deg); }
    45% { transform: rotateY(90deg); }
    50% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
    70% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
    75% { transform: rotateY(270deg); }
    95% { transform: rotateY(270deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}

.qube {
animation: spinCube 8s 1 forwards;
}
```

It would take a bit of tweaking to get the timing right, but it's the only thing I can think of.

Here's a [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLmXgL) of this alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks, this works a treat. I'd not thought of combining into one animation, so this is a good work-around.  Strange little bug this seems to have found though! Answer marked as accepted.